# python screenshot with top of browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, screenshot

I'm trying to make screenshots from multiple URL's. My code is working fine, but as result I get image of an active window. But I need a full screenshot of screen with top of browser (URL)

```
file = open('links.txt', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
urls = file.readlines()

for i, url in enumerate(urls, start=1):
try:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get(url)

browser.save_screenshot(r'C:path\%03d.png' % i)
    browser.quit()
except Exception as err:
    browser.quit()
    break
```

I need this:
[image]
I have this:
[image]

Comment: Are you on windows or some other OS? Do you need multiple OS support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `pillow` and the `pyautogui` modules. You can read about the screen shot functions of these modules [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html).

If that works for you, good. If not, I don't really know what else you can do, but there is probably a different way.

Answer (score 0):

It's working like this! I get 2 screenshots, one with top and the second without

```
 file = open('links.txt', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
urls = file.readlines()




for i, url in enumerate(urls, start=1):
 try:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get(url)
    browser.maximize_window()
    browser.save_screenshot(r'C:\Users\krupn\Desktop\CreateWord\screenshots\%03d.png' % i)
    im1 = pyautogui.screenshot()
    im1.save(r'C:\Users\krupn\Desktop\CreateWord\screenshots\%04d.png' % i)
    browser.quit()
except Exception as err:
    browser.quit()
    break
```